# Performance issuses with nested foreach loops

Tags: c#, linq, foreach, json.net

I don't know if the issue i'm facing is due to nested loops or due to something else (bad code, Large data). let me explain, hope someone can helps me figure it out:-

I'm working on a windows phone 8 app. On launch the app makes three httpclient calls to 3 different pages, then converts the each response (which is html) to xml then to json data(OBS!!! this works fine and no problems with this). At this stage I want to extract data from those 3 json and combine the extracted data into a new Json to be saved to the IsolatedStorage later. To do this extraction I used multiple foreach loops and even sometimes linq **(Here I think is the problem)**. Each foreach loop might do between 50 and >500 iterations. The extraction process takes almost 2 mins, which I think is to much. Below you can see a code snippet from my code:-

```
public async Task LoadData()
    {

        //baseUri definition....

        await CookieHandler.GetCookies(baseUri);

        _reqPList=new RequestResponse();

        await _reqPList.GetResponse(baseUri, pList);  // First page request
        XmlConvertor.ConvertToXml(_reqPList.Response);  //First page convert to xml
        var phoneListResponse = XmlConvertor.XmlString;

        //Second and third page request and convert to xml

        var handler = new DataHandler();
        await handler.phoneListHandler(phoneListResponse);  //First page convert to Json
        //Second and third page convert to Json

        var jObject = JObject.Parse(handler.PhoneListJson);
        var jCollection = jObject["tbody"]["tr"].Children();

        //The start of extracting data

        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        using (var streamWriter=new StreamWriter(stream))
        using (_jsonW = new JsonTextWriter(streamWriter))
        {
                var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            _jsonW.WriteStartArray();
            foreach (var item in jCollection)  //First foreach loop (100 iteration) using the first page
            {
                var arr = item.Value<JArray>("td");
                if (arr == null) continue;
                _jsonW.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
                _jsonW.WriteStartObject();
                _jsonW.WritePropertyName("Name");
                _jsonW.WriteValue(arr[0].Value<string>());
                #region Info Array
                _jsonW.WritePropertyName("Info");
                _jsonW.WriteStartArray();

                // Do some extraction

                _jsonW.WriteEndArray();
                #endregion
                #region Schedule Array
                await ScheduleArrayAsync(item, handler.ScheduleJson, handler); // This method extract data from 2nd page
                #endregion
                #region Current activity
                CurrActivityAsync(item, handler.CurrActivitiesJson); // This method extract data from 3rd page
                #endregion
                _jsonW.WriteEndObject();
            }
            _jsonW.WriteEndArray();
                watch.Stop();
                var j = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;

            await streamWriter.FlushAsync();
            stream.Position = 0;
            using (var streamReader=new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                var json = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
            }
        }
        this.IsDataLoaded = true;
    }

    private void CurrActivityAsync(JToken token, string jString) This method is called 1 time only
    {
        var arr = token.Value<JArray>("td");
        var personNameArray = arr[0].Value<string>().Split(',');
        if (!_owner.Contains(personNameArray[0])) return;
        var jObject = JObject.Parse(jString);
        var jCollection = jObject["tbody"]["tr"].Children();

        _jsonW.WritePropertyName("Current activity");
        _jsonW.WriteStartArray();

        foreach (var array in from item in jCollection   // Second foreach loop (Almost 60 iteration)
            let array = item.Value<JObject>().Value<JArray>("td")
            where array != null && item.Children().Count() > 1
            select array)
        {
            _jsonW.WriteStartObject();

            // do some extraction 

            _jsonW.WriteEndObject();
        }
        _jsonW.WriteEndArray();
    }

    private async Task ScheduleArrayAsync(JToken token, string jString, DataHandler handler)  // This method is called 100 times.
    {
        var arr = token.Value<JArray>("td");
        var personNameArray = arr[0].Value<string>().Split(',');
        var jObject = JObject.Parse(jString);
        var trList = jObject["tbody"]["tr"];
        var selectedArray = default(JArray);
        var weekNumber = trList.SelectMany(tr => tr.SelectTokens("td[1].table.tbody.tr", false))
            .SelectMany(lk => lk.SelectTokens("td", false))
            .Where(j => (!j.HasValues) && (j.Value<string>().Contains("v")))
            .Select(lo => lo.Value<string>())
            .ToArray();

        var psTypeOne = trList.SelectMany(tr => tr.SelectTokens("td[0].a.#text", false))
            .Where(hashText => (hashText.Value<string>().Contains(personNameArray[0])) &&
                         (hashText.Value<string>().Contains(personNameArray[1])))
            .Select(td => td.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent)
            .ToArray();


        if (psTypeOne != null)
        {
            _jsonW.WritePropertyName("Schedule");
            _jsonW.WriteStartArray();
            _jsonW.WriteStartObject();
            _jsonW.WritePropertyName("Week Number");
            _jsonW.WriteValue(weekNumber[0].Remove(0, 2));
            _jsonW.WritePropertyName("Week days");
            _jsonW.WriteStartArray();

            foreach (var day in selectedArray) // 7 itereation
            {
                if (day.SelectToken("table", false) == null) continue;
                _jsonW.WriteStartObject();
                _jsonW.WritePropertyName("Day name");
                var dayname = Convert.ToDateTime(day.Value<string>("@id").Remove(0, 8));
                _jsonW.WriteValue(dayname.DayOfWeek.ToString());
                _jsonW.WritePropertyName("Date");
                _jsonW.WriteValue(day.Value<string>("@id").Remove(0, 8));
                var assignments = day.SelectToken("table.tbody.tr", false);
                _jsonW.WritePropertyName("Assignments");
                _jsonW.WriteStartArray();

                //Foreach loop 2 start or Foreach
                foreach (var assignment in assignments) // between 1 and 5 iterations
                {
                    //Some extractions

                        if (info[0].Contains("slotInfo")) //Here we do some new webrequests and extractions
                        {
                            await _reqPList.GetSlotInfoPost(info[1]);
                            XmlConvertor.ConvertToXml(_reqPList.Response);
                            addedInfo = XmlConvertor.XmlString;
                            await handler.InfoHandler(addedInfo);
                            var jO = JObject.Parse(handler.InfoJson);
                            addedJToken = jO.SelectToken("td");

                            // Some extractions

                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Some code
                    }
                }
                //Foreach loop 2 end
                //Some code to Close the Array
            }
            //Foreach loop 1 end
            //some code to Close the Array
        }
    }
```

Now considering all this iterations and method calls, can i optimize the code to do the processing faster less than 2 mins?

**Edit:-**

Let me give you some more info about the pages i parsed in the begining of my code. First of all it pages belong to an online Schedule site that we use at work. They don't have any API to work with. That is why i need to parse the Httpclient HtmlResponse and convert it to xml then json.

Second each of those pages have a very complex structure combind with bad naming. Please look at below:-

```
<tr class="odd">
<td class="user" onmouseover="userInfo('469');" onmouseout="userInfo(0);" onmousemove="moveSlotInfo();"> User One</td> // User One is needed
<td id="day-469-2014-03-31" style="vertical-align: top;">
  <table class="ss" cellspacing="1">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="as"> </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</td>
<td id="day-469-2014-04-01" style="vertical-align: top;">   // The date is needed
  <table class="ss" cellspacing="1">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="as" style="color: #ffffff; background-color: #4040ff;" onmouseover="this.className=(document.week_vs_doctor.activityId.value==-1?'sd':'sp');slotInfo('177738',false);" onmouseout="this.className='as';slotInfo(0,false);" onmousemove="moveSlotInfo();">KAVAul</td>  // KAVAul is needed
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</td>
```

OBS!!! This is just a demo code to make a point (i know it is not functional).

Even when i convert this to Json it is still in need for adjuctment that is why i decided to rewrite this json according to my needs. Take a look at this code snippet as it shows how i need it.

```
[
{
"Name": "User Name",
"Info": [
  {
    "Signature": "un"
  },
  {
    "Group": "Group1"
  },
  {
    "E-mail": "user.name@group1.com"
  }
],
"Schedule": [
  {
    "Week Number": "14",
    "Week days": [
      {
        "Day name": "Monday",
        "Date": "2014-03-31",
        "Assignments": [
          {
            "Assignment name": "AAA",
            "Assignment time": "07:30 - 16:00",
            "Assignment provider": "BBB, 2014-03-07 16:42"
          }
```

OBS!!! I know the json data needs closing, this is just to make a point.

Comment: What does `handler.InfoHandler(addedInfo)` do? Is there a reason it's async?

Comment: @siride handler.InfoHandler(addedInfo) is a call to an async method to convert data from xml to json. This piece of data is not present in the original 3 pages i parsed.

Comment: why do you need to use async here? Is it really that performance intensive that you save time by doing it that way over doing it synchronously?

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be more simple using [htmlagility pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to simply traverse html from httprequest response.

A custom class which represent exactly you're final object with serializable attribute and the when the class has been filled call javascript serializer to serialize all into a json object(You may use [json converter](http://json2csharp.com/) online to convert json in your custom class so you can simply deserialize json into a custom object without issues and viceversa).

Also there's another importan thing: data dimension. If you're working with few data is it more faster if you work with large data it will require more time have the response and more time to be processed.

May you tell us which are the page involded and which is final json object???

Comment: i have tried htmlagility Pack Before and it didn't fits my need. Anyway i don't Think it is the problem here. Plz take a look at the Edited info. and you will see that converting the original Json to my json is not an easy task and needs manual extraction of data. Please if you Think i missunderstood your answer, provide me with an example so i can understand it better.